# Strange response from WCF service, how to return json easily

Tags: wcf, json

I want to get a service to respond with just JSON. I have written the following code:

```
namespace BM.Security
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class AssocFileService
    {


        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        public List<Person> GetPeople(int message)
        {

            List<Person> myList = new List<Person>();

            Person p = new Person() 
            { 
                Age = 28,
                Name="Name1"
            };
            Person p2 = new Person()
            {
                Age = 26,
                Name = "Name2"
            };

            myList.Add(p);
            myList.Add(p2);



            return myList;
        }

    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Person
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But im getting the following JSON back which is really wierd...

```
{ "d" : [ { "Age" : 28,
        "Name" : "Name1",
        "__type" : "Person:#Bm.Security"
      },
      { "Age" : 26,
        "Name" : "Name2",
        "__type" : "Person:#BM.Security"
      }
    ] }
```

I'm totally stumped by the "d" no idea where that has come from. And also by the __type variable, no thanks don't really want that in my Json :-( How do I set the root node in my data to replace that d? Where did the d come from? So many questions...

Hope someone can help....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `WebInvoke` attribute with `BodyStyle` property like this:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
public List<Person> GetPeople(int message)
{
.
.
.
}
```

When `WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` are specified both **request** and **response** are not wrapped. Please check if this helps.

### UPDATE 1

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
public List<Person> GetPeople(int message);
```

This is working fine on a WCF server on an ASP.NET website

### UPDATE 2

There's one more than you need to do. You need to specify the `endpoint` as `webHttp` in your `web.config` where you may use it as a service too and http requests will be using `WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` which would be without wrapping your JSON.

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="AssocFileServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="AssocFileServiceBehavior" name="BM.Security.AssocFileService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="BM.Security.IAssocFileService" behaviorConfiguration="web" />
  </service>
</services>
```

I have prepared a ASP.NET website. You may [download](http://www.mediafire.com/?aeq1kt0aaf1dm58) and check this out.

Comment: Hi, sorry this doesnt work. The body style 'Bare' is not supported by 'WebScriptEnablingBehavior'. Change the body style to be 'WrappedRequest'. :-(

Comment: After doing some googling, found out this is a security feature that has been added to the JSON serialization in .NET 3.5. It's a container object, so instead of, say, `results[0]`, you would just say `results.d[0]`. Read [this article](http://encosia.com/2009/02/10/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/) for more information.

Comment: @Exitos I just created a WCF service on a ASP.NET website and giving the above attributes on the `OperationContract` and it is working fine.

Comment: When you calling without parameter, please ignore the last trailing `/` and with param `message=hello` won't work because the param is of `int` type, try `message=1`. For your instance. (Try this)[http://localhost:61400/Exitos.Test.WcfJson]/assocfileservice.svc/GetPeople) and (also this)[http://localhost:61400/Exitos.Test.WcfJson/assocfileservice.svc/GetPeople?message=1]

Comment: Sorry yeah, sorry again deleted my comment before I realised you replied. Yeah it works thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1):

WRT to the d: you need an object to contain the array in json.

The type is included by default as part of the JavascriptSerializer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [WCF Web HTTP programming model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412169.aspx) to accomplish this very easily. This is a reasonable and common request, so I've written a blog post on the [Anatomy of a simple REST service](http://www.visualstuart.net/blog2/2011/11/anatomy-of-a-simple-rest-service/) that shows and explains the code, and includes sample code to download. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

The d object wraps an array if it is returned via GET as json as this leaves the user vulnerable to JSON hijacking. A malicious user could get your data by changing the prototype for Object using **defineSetter**. This only works with JSON arrays as they are considered valid javascript and execute as such