# WCF response always starts with "GetResult"

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest

I'm using WCF to create a Rest-JSON API.

The problem is that my results always starts with `{"GetResult": HERE_MY_RESULT }` (notice the "GetResult")

For example:

```
public string GetString()
{
    return "Hello World!";
}
```

returns `{"GetResult": "Hello World!"}`

Here is the relevant code that I'm using for my service:
Service:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPlaceService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
                UriTemplate = "places")]
    PlaceModel Get();
}

public class PlaceService : IPlaceService
{
    public PlaceModel Get()
    {
        return new PlaceModel
        {
            Count = 123,
            Title = "Title",
            Description = "Desc",
        };
    }
}
```

Contract:

```
[DataContract]
public class PlaceModel
{
    [DataMember(Name="count")]
    public int Count { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And the result:

`{"GetResult":{"count":123,"description":"Desc","title":"Title"}}`

Does anybody know how to remove that `"GetResult"` from my JSON result?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the solution inspired on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105912/strange-response-from-wcf-service-how-to-return-json-easily).

Just changing the `BodyStyle` of the `[OperationContract]` to

```
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
```

fixes it, and now Im recieving:

`{"count":123,"data":[],"description":"Desc","title":"Title"}`